# A complete url does not get pass through in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using following code

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url');

function handle_incoming_request (req, res) {
    console.log('Incoming request: (' + req.method + ') ' + req.url);

    req.parsed_url = url.parse(req.url, true);
    console.log(req.parsed_url);
}

var server = http.createServer(handle_incoming_request);
server.listen(8080);
```

Now when I `curl` below

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost:8080/albums/italy2012.json?page=0&page_size=20
```

Then I get below in node console

```
Incoming request: (GET) /albums/italy2012.json?page=0
{ protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: '?page=0',
  query: { page: '0' },
  pathname: '/albums/italy2012.json',
  path: '/albums/italy2012.json?page=0',
  href: '/albums/italy2012.json?page=0' }
```

As you can see in first line the url is half. It is omitting `&page_size=20`

**Why and how can I fix this?**

Comment: curl -i -X GET "http://localhost:8080/albums/italy2012.json?page=0&page_size=20" - try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with how you post via CURL, you need to quote the URL, otherwise the ampersand sign will set CURL as a background process

```
curl -i -X GET "http://localhost:8080/albums/italy2012.json?page=0&page_size=20"
```